# SwiftUI LazyVStack vs UITableView CPU Usage

Tags: ios, uitableview, swiftui-list

I have two identical projects. One was written with SwiftUI and the other with UIKit. But while UIKit consumes 5% CPU, SwiftUI consumes 26% CPU. Does anyone know how I can reduce the CPU used by SwiftUI?

My original question was List vs UITableView. But I saw that LazyVStack was much more efficient than List, thanks to @Paulw11.
But it's still far behind UITableView.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var progress: Double = 0.0
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(1...1000, id: \.self) { value in
                        Text("Hello, world!")
                    }
                }
            }
            Slider(value: $progress, in: 0.0...1.0, step: 0.01)
        }
        .onChange(of: progress, perform: { value in
            print(value)
        })
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let array: Array<String> = Array(repeating: "Hello, world!", count: 1000)
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
    
    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        print(sender.value)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        array.count[enter image description here][1]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[UITableView Project Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xotFI.jpg)

[SwiftUI Project Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Au8ZW.png)

[Download sample projects](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VOWF4H36Ctaim-si_NVIrqpLGPqFIPbw/view)

Comment: You can use the *Time Profiler* instrument to determine where your app is spending time.  One problem I see immediately is that each time your view refreshes you will be recreating the array of 1000 items because SwiftUI views are ephemeral and immutable.  Move that array into an `@State` property or external model and you should see an improvement.

Comment: Replacing the `List` with a `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack` gives you performance similar to the tableview, since that works the same way, rendering only the visible rows

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot. Yes, the CPU usage drops to 25% with `LazyVStack` . It's still far behind  `UITableView` but better than List. I'm updating my question to `LazyVStack` vs `UITableView`.

Comment: @oguz did you figure it out? Also heard List has improved its performance and wonder if you know more about their comparisons

Comment: @hyouuu look at the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@hyouuu The most important part is the progress value. Avoid using the **@Published** value as much as possible in **ViewModel**s. Instead, split the views into subviews and manually set a value to the **ViewModel** as in the example.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var array = Array(1...1000)
    var text = "Hello, world!"
    
    var progress: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print("new value",progress)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Scroll(viewModel: viewModel)
            Slide(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
    }
}

struct Scroll: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.array, id: \.self) { value in Text(viewModel.text)  }
        }
    }
}

struct Slide: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel
    @State var progress:Double = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Slider(value: $progress, in: 0.0...1.0, step: 0.01)
            .onChange(of: progress) { newValue in
                viewModel.progress = newValue
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Did you compare performance to LazyVStack and UITableView by any chance?

Comment: %4(UIKit) vs %7 (SwiftUI). I guess it has nothing to do with LazyVStack or UITableView. The difference coming form sliders. UISlider works better than SwiftUI's Slider. Just delete everything expect sliders and compare them.

Comment: That's great data point! How do you compare LazyVStack to List? When to use which has always confused me here

Comment: Depends on the design. If you need to customization, you should choose LazyVStack. If you want to Apple style & built in specs (like swipe to delete, insertion deletion animations, drop animations), then you should select List. 
As for the performance, LazyVStack seems to be better. Especially if the cells contain images...